# Reputation Distribution by Location

Tags: discussion, reputation, location

Is there a way to find out the users with the highest reputation, in a given location? For example, I want to know who is the highest-ranking user in Argentina. It'd be interesting to find out the reputation distribution as a function of location.

Comment: The locations have, for the most part, been normalized against yahoo's map engine, so you should be able to use a data exchange query to get what you need: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not familiar with stack exchange's data model, could you provide an example of a query involving location/reputation, please?

Comment: Use the search box on http://data.stackexchange.com to find some predefined queries like [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2107/top-100-people-near-me-ordered-by-reputation).  The only caveat to all of these searches is that the users are not required to set their location, and the system does not automatically fill that field in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Users by location, with a minimum reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2803/users-by-location-with-a-minimum-reputation)

[Which country are the users from?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/42162/which-country-are-the-users-from)

Comment: I think this queries are outdated!

Comment: @aF. Probably yes, in which sense? Can you update them?

Comment: For instance, my reputation is kinda old (but I don't know from when). I can't update since I don't know this database.

Comment: I put in location "Dublin" (which is my location in my profile) and I hit run query with minimum reputation 1, It did not show my name there. I dont know if I put in some wrong parameter or the script is buggy, can you confirm?