# Compete regionally on Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

Your profile most likely has this phrase:

> top X% this week/month/quarter/year

Would be nice if you could enable an option to `compete regionally`. For example:

> top X% this week/month/quarter/year in Canada

or

> top X% this week/month/quarter/year in Wisconsin

I read on the net that SO can sometimes help you get hired. This feature may be able to increase your chances, because most employers only compare you with your competitors in the current job market. They don't care if there is a better guy in another state or country, they need someone right here, right now. If you are able to show that out of 100 guys, you are number 1 in, let's say, New York (and you are applying for a position in NY), I think it's a better chance than saying you are top 100 out of 10000 (without any regional binding), even though both facts translate into the same top 1% standing.

Regarding implementation, I suggest going down to country level and to state/province level, where available (for example, US/Canada). Also don't make it public by default, so only if you go to your profile, you will see how you compete regionally. If you like the numbers, you may choose to publish them.

Comment: This will require major changes in the user leagues, doubt that's it's feasible.

Comment: There are already several queries in the Data Explorer to get similar information. Somewhat out of date now, but it might still be useful: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: related: [Reputation Distribution by Location](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114687/165773)

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for the link. For your personal needs - it would probably work, even though there is no query for reputation growth velocity. Reputation by itself does not give you anything. Also, for recruitment use it needs to have a publicly verifiable link, which an employer can click.

Comment: Any comments from downvoters? It is useless to downvote if you never explained why. Yours, cap.

Comment: If you insist: I think this is pointless.

Comment: @minitech: well, thank you for co-operation. It helps to know I am not being downvoted by the herd.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bart hints at, there is a [data.stackexchange query to do this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75612/are-you-one-of-the-top-so-users-in-your-country-or-state). As a side note I wouln't count purely on your reputation to get a leg up in a job interview.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Please note also that top X% of [period-of-time] is not just your reputation, it's a velocity of your reputation growth. It is more representative than just how much reputation you have.

Comment: @Neolisk: That's a good point. You might be able to come up with a query based on the linked one

Comment: I wish I knew your database schema and the API well enough to do this. But even if I did modify it, there is no direct link for the employer to verify it. There has to be a one-click check for the concept to work.