# Data Explorer: Not being listed by rank in a particular location

Tags: support, data-explorer, reputation-leagues

I was surfing the Stack Exchange network and ended up with an interesting site where one can generate queries to produce data from various sites, that is, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Meanwhile, I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114687/332532) and [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120273/332532) which gives link(s) SEDE links on how a list of users' rankings by a particular location can be queried from the Stack Exchange network.

What surprised me was that I wasn't listed at all in the rankings, although I double checked to see if my location was added properly (as you may also verify on my [*profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4373584/ahmad-baktash-hayeri?tab=profile))

[image: Profile settings]

*Note that I've added the location information over 24 hours ago. What I was initially suspecting was that the data might be updated after a period of 24 hours, which proved me wrong*.

You may also confirm this scenario by visiting the [***link for the query on SEDE***](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2803/users-by-location-with-a-minimum-reputation) and entering values like *"Afghanistan"*,  *"Kabul"*, or *"Kabul, Afghanistan"*.

The following is a snapshot of the list as I ran the query:

[image: Rankings by location]

So, what I suspect now is that maybe the query is too old to fetch the information, although I might be proved wrong by fellow Stack Exchange users.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've added the location information over 24 hours ago. What I was initially suspecting was that the data might be updated after a period of 24 hours, which proved me wrong.

That's right, the data is updated **weekly**.

This can be seen in the help section of SEDE, in the FAQ section:

> [image]

So, next update should start on June 19th 3:00am UTC.